# Having a problem using new lines with Lua

Tags: string, lua

the code below is a list of multiple strings, but somehow the /n which insists making a new line gets completely ignored. could someone please help?

```lua
local facts_text = {
"You can use the super seeds \nto beat up pigs easily!",
"Terence's a good avian  \nfor total destruction!",
"You can use Hal backwards \nfor more damage!"
}
```

Comment: how do you use those strings? the newline is correct. if you print those strings they print as intendend.

Comment: basically, a text will be shown having a random string by those.

Comment: then whater you use to display that string cannot display line breaks like that. provide more context. are you using some API?

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with internet domains so no. but here's what the text's script looks like :   local facts_bird_text = ui.Text:new({font = fontBasic})
  facts_bird_text.name = "facts_bird_text"
  facts_bird_text.text = facts_text[_G.math.random(1, #facts_text)]
  self:addChild(facts_bird_text)

Comment: Like @Piglet said, `ui.Text` must not be able to show newlines. We can't know for sure, because `ui` is not standard Lua, and we don't know where it comes from. You should add a tag for the library/framework you're using.

Comment: this is not related to internet domains. no idea why you mention that.  for a single line text display it wouldn't make sense to interpret newline characters. this is probably the case here. you should refer to the manual of the GUI library you're using. it is not caused by the posted strings. when asking questions you should learn to distinguish Lua, the programming language with all its basic functions and things that are added through libraries or the host program. Lua does not know anything about GUIs, fonts and things like that

Comment: i see your point here.